# Response is not getting proper as per our requirement

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring boot with security in java restful API. I want a proper response as per my requirement. i will show you the my database table and require response. i will also show you my tried code.
I have tried but the response is not getting proper as per my requirement. anyone have idea ?? how to do that ?

1. Database Table[image: This is my Event Type table]
2. I want like this response from above table

```
"eventColorLegends": [
    {
      "color": "Red",
      "items": [
        "Musician1",
        "Workshop",
        "Seminart"
        ]
    },
    {
      "color": "Black",
      "items": [
        "Product Launches",
        "Incentive Trips"
      ]
    },
    {
      "color": "Green",
      "items": [
        "Dancing",
        "Rotary - Service Club",
        "Historical/Remembrance"
      ]
    },
    {
      "color": "Yellow",
      "items": [
        "Party",
        "Incubator - Accelerator",
        "Leads - Referral"
      ]
    },
    {
      "color": "Orange",
      "items": [
        "Charity",
        "Non-profit",
        "Rotary - Service Club",
        "Historical/Remembrance",

      ]
    },
    {
      "color": "Coffee",
      "items": [
        "Incubator - Accelerator"
      ]
    },
    {
      "color": "Blue",
      "items": [
        "Leads - Referral",
        "Historical/Remembrance",
        "Rotary - Service Club",
        "For-Profit Company",

      ]
    },
]
```

3. I have try code in serviceImpl class

```
public GenericResponse findAllTypeOfEvents() {
        try {
            List<TypesOfEvents> typesOfEventsList = typeOfEventsDao.findAll();
            List<String> listEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < typesOfEventsList.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < typesOfEventsList.size()- 1; j++) {
                    if (typesOfEventsList.get(i).getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(typesOfEventsList.get(j).getColor())) {
                        if (typesOfEventsList.get(j).getType().equalsIgnoreCase(typesOfEventsList.get(j).getType())){
                            listEvents.add(i,typesOfEventsList.get(j).getType());
                            System.out.println(typesOfEventsList.get(i).getColor() + " : " + typesOfEventsList.get(j).getType());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return APIResponseBuilder.build(true, listEvents.toArray(), typesOfEventsList.size() > 0 ? commonMessages.findAllTrue : commonMessages.findAllFalse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(commonMessages.findAllException + "TypesOfEvents " + e.getMessage());
            return APIResponseBuilder.build(false, e.getMessage(), commonMessages.exception);
        }
    }
```

4.MY Response

```
"data": [
    "Seminart",
    "For-Profit Company",
    "For-Profit Company",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Rotary - Service Club",
    "For-Profit Company",
    "For-Profit Company",
    "For-Profit Company",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Seminart",
    "Seminart",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Workshop",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "For-Profit Company",
    "Incubator - Accelerator",
    "Seminart",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "Incubator - Accelerator",
    "For-Profit Company",
    "Incubator - Accelerator",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Rotary - Service Club",
    "Incubator - Accelerator",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Rotary - Service Club",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "Workshop",
    "Seminart",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Rotary - Service Club",
    "Non-profit",
    "Incubator - Accelerator",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Rotary - Service Club",
    "Leads - Referral",
    "Incubator - Accelerator",
    "Rotary - Service Club",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Historical/Remembrance",
    "Incentive Trips",
    "Workshop",
    "Seminart",
    "Workshop"
  ]
}
```

Comment: that is very good, but why did you not post your data as text or dbfiddle, when you are at it.

Comment: I had Added my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Map<String, List<String>>` to map a list of type for each color.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < typesOfEventsList.size(); i++) {
     if (fruits.containsKey(typesOfEventsList.get(i).getColor())){
          List<String> list = map.get(typesOfEventsList.get(i).getColor());
          list.add(typesOfEventsList.get(i).getType());
          map.put(typesOfEventsList.get(i).getColor(), list);
     } else {
         List<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
         list.add(typesOfEventsList.get(i).getType());
         map.put(typesOfEventsList.get(i).getColor(), list);
    }
}
```

Then create class `TypeByColor`

```
class TypeByColor {
    String color;
    List<String> items;
}
```

Then create list from map

```
    List<TypeByColor> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : map.keySet())  
    { 
        list.add(new TypeByColor(name,map.get(name)));
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me how to // update the list for that key

Comment: List<TypeByColor> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : map.keySet())  
    { 
        list.add(new TypeByColor(name,map.get(name)));
    }   this code which place to put

Comment: same place where you put all the code & I will be happy if you upvote my answer also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212057/discussion-between-rajesh-bhushan-and-abinash-ghosh).